# (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) Assign first workspace to secondary monitor in GNOME?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, display, workspaces

Is it possible to assign the first workspace to the secondary monitor, so that all windows in the first workspace appear on the secondary monitor, and all other workspaces appear on the primary monitor?

I'm using GNOME on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

There is application called "GNOME Tweak Tool" aka. "GNOME Tweaks" here you can under Workspaces manage "Display Handling"

To install it from terminal use: `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

[image]

You can also try to look for answers in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80774/separate-workspaces-on-each-monitor) question, but it's probably not worth it.